# Limit 1 result in XML query with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, limit

I've got the following PHP code:

```
$file = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getInfo/en/xml/937a7e45f8f9e50cdb80e21fa50abc39/6479';
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)) {
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);
}
    foreach($xml->movies->movie->images->image as $image) {
        if(strcmp($image['size'],"cover") == 0) {
                echo "".$image['url']."<br/ >";
        }
    }
```

In the XML file there are multiple images with size="cover". How can I limit the result of the above code to just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a foreach statement. `$image = $xml->movies->movie->images->image;` will give you 1 image (prolly the first one though, that may be a bad thing, depends on your usage).

EDIT, this works pretty good too, and you don't have to rely on the images being in a specific order:

```
foreach($xml->movies->movie->images->image as $image) {

    if ($image['size'] == 'cover') {
        echo "IMG:".$image['url']."<br/ >";
        break; //STOPS LOOP ON FIRST IMAGE
    }
}
```

Comment: That does give me the first image, but the very first. Is there and kind of if statement I can use to get the first image with size="cover" ?

Comment: If the image is in the same order everytime, you could try this `$image = $xml-xpath('/opensearchdescription/movies/movie/images/image[3]');`. There's also this for dealing directly with attributes: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Ah thanks :D It was [2] as I believe it starts at [0]. Thanks for your help :D:D

Comment: ahh k, I just used firebug to copy the xpath, makes it easy.

Comment: Ah thanks PiZzL3, I tried breaking the loop earlier but couldn't quite work out how to do it. Thanks :D